# How to create the select box group in the following scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I have a set of date string, which is unique

```
eg.

2012 04 01
2012 04 10
2012 04 25
2012 06 30
2012 06 10
2012 12 01
2013 04 01
```

What I need to do is to create 3 select box, one for year, one for month and one for day

The problem is I need to maintain the relationship of among year month and day

For example, first the user can view 2012 2013, then if 2012, 04, 06, 12 is shown for month, if select 04 as month, 01 , 10, 25 is shown for day

The implementation is:

```
                for (var key in data) {
                    year = key.substring(0,4);
                    if ($.inArray(year, yearArr) == '-1'){
                        yearArr.push(year);
                        $('#year').append('<option value="' + year + '">' + year + '</option>');
                    }
                    dateArr.push(key);
                    chtml.push("<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + data[key] + "</td></tr>");
                }
```

Where Key is each date string abd dateArr stored all date

```
$("#year").change(function(){
    var month;
    var monthArr = [];
    var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    if (selectedValue !== '-1') {
        $('#month').prop("disabled", false);
        $('#month').empty().append('<option value="-1">Please choose</option>');
        for (var key in dateArr) {
            if (selectedValue == key.substring(0,4)) {
                month = key.substring(4,2);
                if ($.inArray(month, monthArr) == '-1'){
                    monthArr.push(month);
                    $('#month').append('<option value="' + month + '">' + month + '</option>');
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $('#month,#day').empty().append('<option value="-1">Please choose</option>');
    }
});

$("#month").change(function(){
    var day;
    var dayArr = [];
    var selectedValue = $("#year").find(":selected").val() + $(this).find(":selected").val();
    if (selectedValue !== '-1') {
        $('#day').prop("disabled", false);
        $('#day').empty().append('<option value="-1">Please choose</option>');
        for (var key in dateArr) {
            if (selectedValue == key.substring(0,6)) {
                day = key.substring(6,2);
                if ($.inArray(day, dayArr) == '-1'){
                    dayArr.push(day);
                    $('#day').append('<option value="' + day + '">' + day + '</option>');
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $('#month,#day').empty().append('<option value="-1">Please choose</option>');
    }
});
```

When select box year or month is change, append the correspond value, but that is not working because when user change month, they can back to change the year, how to fix the problem? Or any simpler way recommended to do it? thanks

Comment: why don't you use some good plugin for day, month and year picker while keeping relations between them. like http://www.amdonnelly.co.uk/experiments/date-drop-down-lists.aspx

Comment: There are plenty of other plugins available out there.

Comment: Is it possible to change jquery ui datepicker to the similar select box?

Comment: That would be difficult task, the link i gave you is not according to your requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your help because I perfer not adding new plugin